# I can't get SASM to run on Linux

Tags: assembly, nasm, sasm

I'm new to linux, I don't know a lot about building and stuff. I tried to install sasm: Downloaded it, extracted it, tried all the different ways to install it, but NONE work.

http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2016/10/installing-sasm-assembly-ide-in-ubuntu.html

...is the only proper guide I found, but, maybe cause the given link to install SASM is dead, it doesn't want to work. Is there anyone who can help me on this?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: What do you mean with not working? Any error messages?

Comment: Did you follow each step as described in the link? At which step did you get an error?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, i just installed SASM IDE in one newly installed Ubuntu 18.06 LTS box, so no, it does not seems dead at all. The steps i followed:

Update and upgrade your system dependecies:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade;
```

Then browse to http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Dman95/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/ and download the .deb package (sasm_3.10.1_amd64.deb)

Navigate to the download directory and use the dpkg utility to try to install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i sasm_3.10.1_amd64.deb
```

It will probably fail, due to lack of package dependencies. It is normal and expected behavior.

> dpkg: error processing package sasm (--install):  dependency problems
>   - leaving unconfigured
>   ...

Ok, go on and install the missing dependecy with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

apt will now install what sasm is requiring. After the install process, just launch sasm with:

```
sasm
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, No i meant dead as in the link he posted in his tutorial didn't work. Thanks though, I now got it running